# C# Go to beginning of loop (continue or break?)

Tags: c#, loops, break, continue

This program randomly creates a number between 1 and 50 that the user needs to guess. I want to restart the while loop when the user's guess is incorrect. I have tried using break and continue to do this, but either I am doing it wrong or it is not the best solution. Also, when the user input is incorrect they are asked if they want to guess again. I also tried exiting that loop with break or continue with similar results. Any suggestions?

```
Console.WriteLine("I am thinking of a whole number between 1 and 50. Enter your guess.");
        string userGuess;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int compNum = rnd.Next(1, 50);
        int guessToInt;
        int numOfTries = 0;
        string cont;
        bool correct = false;
        //TODO Delete this line when finished
        Console.WriteLine($"Answer " + compNum);

        //Trying to get new user input if guess is wrong
        while (correct == false)
        {
            //correct = false;
            numOfTries++;
            userGuess = Console.ReadLine();
            guessToInt = Int32.Parse(userGuess);

            if (guessToInt == compNum)
            {
                numOfTries++;
                correct = true;
                Console.WriteLine($"Your guess is correct! The number was " + compNum + ". Congratulations. It only took you " + numOfTries + " guess(es).");
            }

            else if (guessToInt < 1 || guessToInt > 50)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect input. Enter a whole number between 1 and 50. Try again.");
                //numOfTries++;
                correct = false;
                continue;
            }

            else if (guessToInt != compNum)
            {
                //How do I get new user input?
                Console.WriteLine("Your guess is incorrect. Would you like to try again? Y or N?");
                //numOfTries++;
                correct = false;
                cont = Console.ReadLine();

                if (cont == "Y")
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else Console.WriteLine("Bye."); Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It seems to me that this code works. What is exactly the problem?

Comment: `break` will break the loop and ignore all following occurrences whereas `continue` will skip the current loop execution and continue with the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Few problems:

1. You don't have to set the boolean to false each time. It is already set to false at start
2. `else Console.WriteLine("Bye."); Environment.Exit(0);`
   Since you didn't add curly brackets (which I strongly advise you to never do),
   Only the first command will operate under the statement.
   The "Environment.Exit" will always occur.

For the rest, I added the fixes to your code.

```cs
Console.WriteLine("I am thinking of a whole number between 1 and 50. Enter your guess.");
string userGuess;
Random rnd = new Random();
int compNum = rnd.Next(1, 50);
int guessToInt;
int numOfTries = 0;
string cont;
bool correct = false;
//TODO Delete this line when finished
Console.WriteLine($"Answer " + compNum);

//Trying to get new user input if guess is wrong
while (correct == false)
{
    //correct = false;
    numOfTries++;
    userGuess = Console.ReadLine();
    guessToInt = Int32.Parse(userGuess);

    if (guessToInt == compNum)
    {
        numOfTries++;
        correct = true;
        Console.WriteLine($"Your guess is correct! The number was " + compNum + ". Congratulations. It only took you " + numOfTries + " guess(es).");
    }

    else if (guessToInt < 1 || guessToInt > 50)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect input. Enter a whole number between 1 and 50. Try again.");
        //numOfTries++;
        //**correct = false; --> No need, correct was already false
        //**continue; --> No need, will continue anyway
    }

    else if (guessToInt != compNum)
    {
        //How do I get new user input?
        Console.WriteLine("Your guess is incorrect. Would you like to try again? Y or N?");
        cont = Console.ReadLine();
        //numOfTries++;
        //**correct = false; --> No need, correct was already false

        //** if (cont == "Y") --> No need, will continue anyway
        //** {
        //**     continue;
        //** }

        // else Console.WriteLine("Bye."); Environment.Exit(0); --> 
        //** "else" without brackets will 
        if (cont != "Y") 
        {
            break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your next guess:");
    }
}
```

NOTE: I haven't touched the "numOfTries" feature since not mentioned in the question

Comment: Forgot to remove _numOfTries++_ in the correct guess block

Comment: Thank you. I understand better now.